# mysql timespan in timespan

Tags: php, mysql

I got a mysql table with columns `from_date` and `to_date`.

I also got a second timespan in PHP consisting of `$monday` and `$friday`.

Now I want to select all entries from my table which's timespan includes atleast one day inbetween `$monday` and `$friday`.

I first thought about something like this:

```
WHERE `from_date` >= :monday
AND `to_date` <= :friday
```

But this would not include entries where `from_date` is smaller then `:monday` or `to_date` is greater then `:friday`

Comment: That is because **I want to select all entries from my table whose timespan includes atleast one day between `$monday` and `$friday`.**

Comment: Yes, I know. I am looking for a query which does this.

Comment: Since you want something between Monday and Friday; your query is correct, and your question is contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to select records which start before the end of your range and end after the start of it:

```sql
WHERE from_date <= :friday AND to_date >= :monday
```